# Which error tracking system to choose for a PHP application?

Tags: php, notification, tracking

At this moment I am selecting an error tracking system for a PHP application.

I found only [Errbit](https://errbit.com/) which is supposed to be used with this library: [errbitPHP](https://github.com/emgiezet/errbitPHP).

What I want:

1. Self-hosted application
2. Error grouping (most wanted)
3. Detail and custom error information (stack trace, my custom PHP process identifier that I use for grepping through logs etc)
4. Some kind of notification that we got a new error, identified by new stack trace maybe
5. And optional, some metrics for cases when we got more errors than usual (it is legacy application and most errors is not errors at all, for example just validations errors, in perspective validation should became more silent)

At this moment no operation system is selected, but I think admins prefer Ubuntu LTS.

I tried to Google some alternatives, but found only commercial products that aren't self-hosted. Are there any self-hosted errbit alternatives, which of them are most usable? Or is errbit the best what I can get?

Comment: Note that you can actually use Errbit with almost any Airbrake.io client library, but Sentry is better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would strongly recommend [Sentry on Premise](https://github.com/getsentry/onpremise)

- Self-hosted application [✓](https://github.com/getsentry/onpremise/blob/master/README.md)
- Error grouping (most wanted) [✓](https://docs.sentry.io/data-management/rollups/)
- Detail and custom error information
  (stacktrace, my custom php process identifier that i use for grepping
  through logs etc) [✓](https://docs.sentry.io/enriching-error-data/context/?platform=python)
- Some kind of notification that we got new error,
  identified by new stacktrace maybe [✓](https://docs.sentry.io/workflow/notifications/)
- And optional, some metrics for
  cases when we got more errors than usual (it is legacy application
  and most errors is not errors at all, for example just validations
  errors, in perspective validation should became more silent) [✓](https://sentry.io/_/resources/customer-success/alert-rules/)
- At this moment no operation system selected, but i think amdins prefer Ubuntu LTS. **(Docker)** [✓](https://docs.sentry.io/server/installation/docker/) or **(Ubuntu directly)** [✓](https://docs.sentry.io/server/installation/python/#install-sentry)

[image: more]

Comment: Oh, i don't noticed this self-hosted option, is pricing same for self-hosted application? Or pricing related only with sentry-hosted application?

Comment: It's free, when you self-host!

Comment: Sounds perfect! I try it on localhost.

Comment: We switched from Errbit to self-hosted Sentry about two years ago, and we are very happy with Sentry.